# refman.rtf fails to use equation from '*.md' in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I use '*.md' to generate '(index*).html' and '(refman*).rtf' documentation with doxygen 1.8.14.

The mathematical equation in '*.md' gives a correct equation in html output but not in the file 'refman.rtf'. The other theoretical parts like paragraph and other stuff work well between *.md and rtf output.

I guess *.rtf is not recognizing the equation part of the *.md document.

Does the RTF generation through doxygen read the *.md files?

Do I need to change any tag to make *.md work with rtf output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only for markdown but also for "normal" doxygen input formulas do not work.

From the documentation:

> Doxygen allows you to put LATEX formulas in the output (this works
>   only for the HTML and LATEX output, not for the RTF nor for the man
>   page output).

A workaround workflow, at the moment for non inline formulas, is to do something like:

- Create an image with the formula e.g in a dummy doxygen run where one does not use MATHJAX, this will result in an image with a name like: 'form_0.png'.

In the code one has to place an if construct like:

```
\if rtf_run
  \image rtf form_0.png
\else
  \f... with the formula
\endif
```

One now has to run doxygen twice:

- once for the output without *rtf*, i.e. without setting `rtf_run` in `ENABLED_SECTIONS`
- once for *rtf* output by setting `rtf_run` in `ENABLED_SECTIONS`

EDIT June 5, 2018: I've just pushed a proposed patch to github [pull request 756](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/756). Here the formulas are rendered as `png` images and included in the RTF documentation.

EDIT: 2018/06/10: The push request has been integrated in the master version on github.